# Is it possible to make custom restful APIs for existing phpfox web application

Tags: php, web-services, rest, phpfox

We have a web application which is built in phpfox now we are going to develop a mobile application too (android and ios). So is any module or plugin available for phpfox restful apis or we need to write custom code for web service. I didn't find any useful link or example for phpfox webservices. Please help me to find best possible solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

no plugins are available for this, you have to create custom restful API.